# C# Failing Covariant Cast

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, variance

I'm trying to create something like a generic table factory with a range of implementations. Example below is self explanatory, and the cast in the end isn't working even though both type attributes marked as 'out'. I suppose, the issue is that Table isn't an interface and this breaks the cast. But it shuldn't really be interface and especially not covariant. Any ideas how to cast it properly? Definitely don't want to use reflection to use methods.

```
interface ITableRow { }

class Table<T> where T : ITableRow { }

interface ITableFactory<out TRow, out TTable>
    where TRow : ITableRow
    where TTable : Table<TRow>
{
    TTable CreateTable();
}

// example implementation:

class SuperRow : ITableRow { }

class SuperTableFactory : ITableFactory<SuperRow, Table<SuperRow>>
{
    public Table<SuperRow> CreateTable() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

// run:

class VarianceTest
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var factory = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Snippets.Var.SuperTableFactory"));

        var casted = (ITableFactory<ITableRow, Table<ITableRow>>) factory; // cast fails
    }
}
```

Comment: Dotnetfiddle demonstrating the issue: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MsDbQu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `SuperTableFactory` claims to produce instances of `Table<SuperRow>`. That means, whatever table you get back from it, you can add `SuperRows`, and read `SuperRows`.

However, your `ITableFactory<ITableRow, Table<ITableRow>>` claims that it produces `Table<ITableRows>` -- tables that people can add `ITableRows` to and read `ITableRows` from.

But your actual table factory produces `Table<SuperRow>`s -- the underlying row storage is `SuperRow`. You can't let someone put any old `ITableRow` in there!

That's why your cast is failing.

You can get around this if you get rid of the "people can add rows to tables" bit, and promise that people can only ever read rows. Then it doesn't matter whether a `Table`'s row storage is actually `SuperRow`, as people can't try and put other types of row in there.

You do this by making `Table<T>` covariant. But as you noted, classes can't be covariant, only interfaces. So you'll need an `ITable<out T>`.

Comment: The best explanation, thanks a lot. The thing is Table can't really be covariant, it's got things like List<Column<T>> and stuff like that. I'm trying to find a workaroud now making a factory to have an abstract class in between the interface and implementation..

Comment: Right - so people *can* add rows, so you can't pretend that a `Table<SuperRow>` is actually a `Table<ITableRow>`, as then people will be able to add other sorts of row.

Comment: No they can't add rows, but Table has for example the list of column definitions, which doesn't let me mark ITableRow as OUT type: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7sqtIX

Comment: `Column` also needs to be covariant of course (so `IColumn<out T>`) and your `Columns` property must not be settable